# AHK: Sending Email Issue

Tags: autohotkey

I use below code to send email using AHK. It works when I use literal strings in subject and message body. But when I try to use %variable%, the resultant email received has blank subject/message body.

```
Order := 
Order = %Order% `n FAX MESSAGE
Order = %Order% `n
Order = %Order% `n Sent: %DateString% %TimeString%

pmsg            := ComObjCreate("CDO.Message")
pmsg.From       := """Lens Shapers"" <fax@l******s.com>"
pmsg.To         := "k*******r@gmail.com"
pmsg.BCC        := "" 
pmsg.CC         := "" 
pmsg.Subject    := "Lenses are Ready" **;THIS SUBJECT IS TRANSMITTED GOOD**
pmsg.TextBody   := %Order% **;THIS MESSAGE BODY IS BLANK WHEN EMAIL IS RECEIVED**
sAttach         := "" 

fields := Object()
fields.smtpserver   := "smtp.gmail.com" ; specify your SMTP server
fields.smtpserverport     := 465 ; 25
fields.smtpusessl      := True ; False
fields.sendusing     := 2   ; cdoSendUsingPort
fields.smtpauthenticate     := 1   ; cdoBasic
fields.sendusername := "k*****f@l******s.com"
fields.sendpassword := "PASSWORD"
fields.smtpconnectiontimeout := 60
schema := "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"

pfld :=   pmsg.Configuration.Fields

For field,value in fields
    pfld.Item(schema . field) := value
pfld.Update()

Loop, Parse, sAttach, |, %A_Space%%A_Tab%
  pmsg.AddAttachment(A_LoopField)
pmsg.Send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, but when you use a variable in an expression, you don't use the `%`'s and when you use "`:=`" that is an assignment of an expression.  So try:

```
pmsg.TextBody   := Order
```

As that should work.  If you also need text elements, you need to use quotes around literals and the dot concatenation:

```
pmsg.TextBody   := "Order: " . Order . "`n`n"  ;  also follows with 2 new lines
```

Hth,